# Protocolo comunicación QT Terminal application con STM32F4 por Wireless

Tags: c++, qt

En primer lugar, gracias por la ayuda. Bueno, al lío.
Estoy trabajando en un sistema de telemetría y adquisición de datos para un vehículo. He utilizado en QT como base el proyecto de ejemplo llamado "Terminal" para crear interfaz de telemetría que corre en el ordenador, mientras que en el vehículo hay una STM32F4 (parecida a la Discovery, pero modificada) conectada a multitud de sensores y a una antena. Dicha STM32F4 recolecta datos de los sensores y los guarda en una SD, al tiempo que también manda dichos datos en tiempo real a la interfaz de telemetría. Con lo que tengo actualmente, la interfaz recibe y muestra los datos por pantalla tal y como debería, sin embargo, la idea es también enviar datos al vehículo (para cambiar parámetros de configuración y similares), pero hasta la fecha no he sido incapaz. Parece que la interfaz no enviase datos de ningún tipo o que el vehículo no procesa correctamente la información que recibe.

El código que uso para intentar transmitir desde la interfaz y recibirlo tiene esta pinta:

En la interfaz:

```
typedef enum{
...
GreenFlag,  
RedFlag,  
...
} FLAGSData_t;

//Código, código

void MainWindow::on_GreenFlag_clicked()  
{  
    quint8 buffer[10];   
    int ind=0;
    FLAGSData_t flagsAID;
    showStatusMessage(tr("Green Flag"));
    flagsAID=GreenFlag; //=4
    sending=true;
    buffer[ind++]=FLAGS_CONFIG; //=9
    utility::buffer_append_int16(buffer,flagsAID,&ind);
    mPacket->sendPacket(buffer,ind);
    sending=false;
}
```

(Hay más funciones similares que se activan como esta al pulsar un botón)

En el vehículo receptor:

```
void processPacket(unsigned char *data, unsigned int len){  
int flagsAID;   

uint8_t packet_id;
uint32_t ind=0;  
packet_id = data[0];  
data++;  
switch (packet_id){  

    case FLAGS_CONFIG:  
        flagsAID=buffer2int16(data,&ind);  
        sendFlagsData(flagsAID);  
        break;  
    // Más bloques case similares //  
    }  
}
```

Packet lo uso también para enviar datos del vehículo a la interfaz, cosa que si funciona, por lo que creo que no es el problema.
¿Veis o podéis intuir que estoy haciendo mal? Soy aún relativamente nuevo en esto de programar, así que disculpad si falta información o cometo errores de principiante.
Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Generalmente cuando programamos via serial se generan tareas bloqueantes o similares, te recomiendo usar QSerialPort, este modulo de qt maneja la comunicacion serial de forma muy amigable de modo que trabaja en forma sencilla con la GUI.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En el proyecto ya está implementado QSerialPort, pero no parece tener ningún efecto, tal vez porque lo haya configurado mal o por cualquier otro motivo. Sea como fuere, me he basado en los ejemplos que hay, sobretodo en el ejemplo del terminal, en el que se basa mi aplicación. ¿Algún consejo sobre como configurar QSerialPort?